# GTK# - toolbar buttons with custom images

Tags: xamarin, gtk#

When you create toolbar with buttons in GTK# in Xamarin Studio it seems that you can only assign images by StockId (Stock.New, Stock.Open etc).
Is there any way to assign custom images to toolbar buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a `Widget` as a parameter in the `ToolButton` constructor:

```
var tbar = new Toolbar();
var icon = new Image("icon.png");
var button = new ToolButton(icon, "SO");
tbar.Add(button);
```

In this case, `icon.png` with no path assigned to it, should exist in the application directory, so set it to "Copy To Output Directory".

You can also create the `Image` by passing a Gdk image and mask, but that is another story...